# iOS Slide-Out Sidebar Navigation Bar issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mobile, uinavigationcontroller

I'm creating a slide-out menu sidebar for my app using  storyboard. I followed this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/ right here from beginning to end. The slide-out works perfectly with no issue. My only issue I am having is with the navigation bar. When I ever connect my views to one of the menu options and run the program two navigation bars appear. One with from the one I created and the other I'm not sure where its coming from.

I went through the sample project and added a uitableview controller in there as well and it did the same thing. I tried setting it through the inspector "Top-bar: navigation bar" but when it will not allow me to drop navigation bar button in. Help please!!

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong that causes two navigation bars to appear?

Comment: you can hide you navigation bar ...

Comment: Kalpesh I tried that in view did load, but no luck

Comment: are you using storyboard? and post your code for hidden

Comment: @Kalpesh yes I am, and tried it throught top bar - none using the inspector

Comment: then select navigationcontroller from storyboard and select navigation bar  set its hidden property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select navigationcontroller from storyboard and  set its showwnavigationbar property
```

[image]